# High Reputation on SuperUser without any posts?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

A user 'DAMAN' has 101 reputation on superuser without any answer and a single question with 0 score.  Where has his reputation come from? He is just member since 5 days?

[Link To DAMAN'S Page.](https://superuser.com/users/1106787/daman)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will probably be moved to [meta](https://meta.superuser.com/)

In short, users who are active on other sites in the stack exchange network [gets an association bonus of 100 reputation points](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations/) on this site. The requirement is to have above 200 reputation points on an SE site.

The reason is that such users probably know the format, and some of the restrictions for new users, such as commenting, doesn't make sense for users that knows the format.

In addition, 100 is *not* high reputation. It essentially bypasses some checks placed on new users, such as voting, commenting on other peoples questions, participate in chat etc.

High reputation is a couple of thousand and upwards, where you get privileges such as edit questions and answers without approval, vote to close and so forth.

Comment: Indeed, if you look at the users Reputation tab it confirms that this is the reason. https://superuser.com/users/1106787/daman?tab=reputation

Comment: But still, on stack overflow, He too got an association bonus but he is not on any other platform? How did he got the bonus on stack overflow?

Comment: @BhavyaGupta, It's possible to mark communities as hidden so they won't show on your profile.  That's probably what's happened.

Comment: [Daman has 776 rep on Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/519543/daman)